# Django: Custom field mapping for ModelSerializer

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm hosting an API and for that, I'm using [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/). I have a Model and I'm getting some data through the API to store in the DB through models & model serializers.

My problem is that the column names in the MySQL table are different than the data I'm getting on the API hosted. eg:

Data Got through API:

```
{
    "a": "b",
    "c": "d",
    "e": "f",
}
```

And my Model is as below:

```
class Table(models.Model):
    x  = models.CharField(max_length=25,primary_key=True)
    y  = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    z  = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

Serializer:

```
class TableSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Table
        fields = ( 'x', 'y', 'z')
```

How can I map `a -> x` , `b -> y` , `c -> z` ?

Comment: How about a new serializer with a,b,c and map in the create method?

Answer (score 5):

In your TableSerializer class, you can create your mapping manually:

```
class TableSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    a = models.CharField(source='x', max_length=25, primary_key=True)
    b = models.CharField(source='y', max_length=25)
    c = models.CharField(source='z', max_length=25)

    class Meta:
        model = Table
        fields = ( 'a', 'b', 'c')
```

When you return a Table instance, the `x`, `y` and `z` properties will be serialized as `a`, `b` and `c`.
Similarly, when you get some data through your API, the fields will be mapped the other way around.

You'll get some more info about `source` in the [DRF docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source)

ilse2005's approach works: you can override the create method in your serializer and do the mapping all by yourself but adding the `source` parameter in your serializer fields, this will let you create, update and return `Table` instances easily.